# Does Descartes' theorem work for non-convex polyhedrons?

Tags: general-topology, polyhedra

Does Descartes' theorem work for non-convex polyhedrons? and if it does what are the characteristics of 3 dimensional shapes that don't fall under Descartes' theorem?

Comment: If you mean Descartes' Theorem regarding the [angular defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_defect#Descartes'_theorem) of a polyhedron, then (as noted in the Wikipedia article) convexity is not a requirement.

Comment: thank you! According to the link a shape only needs to be homeomorphic. Is there any direct way of knowing whether a shape is homeomorphic or not?

Comment: That is a concept of topology. Mainly it states that the polyhedron ought not have self-intersections and no handles (holes running through, like in a torus). You also could think about it like blowing it up like an balloon. As long as thereby no singularity occurs and the result would be a sphere, then you are done.